# Is there in Vue.js something like createContext in React?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

Is there in Vue.js something like createContext in React? https://flaviocopes.com/react-context-api/

I found this https://github.com/zephraph/vue-context-api but I would prefer to use something more “official”

Comment: While Vue 2 doesn't have an official equivalent to the context API, Vue 3 has the composition API which may help achieve what you want. You can also use Vuex, which might be just what you need.

Comment: Thank you @LielFridman . As far as I see, Vue 3 "production-grade" will be available in few months. At the moment I can try to use Vuex for my purposes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The most similar thing Vue has to React's contexts is the [Provide / Inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity) options, also available in [Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject).

In fact it was initially [designed after React contexts](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4029).

The usage in vue requires defining a `provide` property on the ancestor component and an `inject` property on the descendant.

```
Vue.component('ancestor', {
  template: '<div>Ancestor: <slot></slot></div>',
  provide: {
    providedKey: 123
  }
})

Vue.component('descendant', {
  template: '<div>Descendant of {{ancestorData}}</div>',
  inject: {
    ancestorData: 'providedKey'
  }
})
```

Then you can do:

```
<ancestor>
 <descendant />
 <descendant />
 <descendant />
</ancestor>
```

And it also works for deeply nested components, they don't need to be direct descendants.